# SharedPreferences save only the Default Value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to get integer Value from Second activity and save in the main activity
and its succeed
i tried to save that value in SharedPreferences
the problem every time im re-open the app
and check saved date in SharedPreferences I found the default  value ( in this case LanguageSelected,1 )

What is the problem?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    languageCheck = intent.getIntExtra(Language.LanguageSelected,1);
                    // saving data
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("whatsappfastmessage",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("languageValue", languageCheck);

    editor.commit();
       
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("whatsappfastmessage",MODE_PRIVATE);
    savedValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("languageValue", languageCheck);
```

Answer (score 0):

i Solved the issue ,

i didn't know that SharedPreferences file can be access from any activities
just write the code of retrieve

best regards